# Install4j update Setup asks to overwrite install4j files

Tags: install4j

When I use my install4j setup to update my existing installation it asks if the files .install4j/i4jinst.dll and unistall.exe should be overridden.
Is this a bug or do i have to configure something?
And if I unistall the updated application those files won't be deleted.

Further information are in the comments.

Comment: That is definitely not normal and must be related to a special condition in your project. Does .install4j/files.log contain these files after the installation?

Comment: @IngoKegel
Yes the files.log contains them.
`<entry name=".install4j\i4jinst.dll" shared="false" uninstallMode="0"/>
<entry name="uninstall.exe" shared="false" uninstallMode="0"/>`

Comment: That's OK. Can you post the part of .install4j/installation.log where the file i4jinst.dll is installed?

Comment: @IngoKegel Sure
`Install file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Stegmann Systems\APS Desktop 2.10\.install4j\i4jdel.exe; size: 79904 bytes; exists: false
       Install file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Stegmann Systems\APS Desktop 2.10\.install4j\i4jinst.dll; size: 135680 bytes; exists: false
       Install file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Stegmann Systems\APS Desktop 2.10\uninstall.exe; size: 329784 bytes; exists: false
       File options set to: [fileTime: Thu Mar 16 15:19:40 CET 2017, mode: 700, overwriteMode: If newer otherwise ask, shared: false, uninstallMode: If created, delayIfNecessary: false]`

Comment: It says "exists: false". Do you add the .install4j folder in your distribution tree?

Comment: No this excerpt is from the initial installation. The following is from an update installation. `Install file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Stegmann Systems\APS Desktop 2.10\.install4j\i4jinst.dll; size: 135680 bytes; exists: true
       Install file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Stegmann Systems\APS Desktop 2.10\uninstall.exe; size: 329784 bytes; exists: true
       File options set to: [fileTime: Fri Mar 17 11:42:50 CET 2017, mode: 700, overwriteMode: If newer otherwise ask, shared: false, uninstallMode: If created, delayIfNecessary: false]`

Comment: What is the previously set overwriteMode before the installation of i4jinst.dll?

Comment: This is the last File options set to block before the installation of the i4jinst.dll `File options set to: [fileTime: Fri Mar 17 11:42:50 CET 2017, mode: 644, overwriteMode: Always ask except for update, shared: false, uninstallMode: If created, delayIfNecessary: false]`

Comment: @IngoKegel do you have an idea what it is?

Comment: Unfortunately not, please send the files installation.log from the initial installation and from the update installation to support@ej-technologies.com